# How to use "Mon May 11 2020 11:22:19 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)" as a date in BigQuery

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery

Is it possible to make a query to convert "Mon May 11 2020 11:22:19 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)" to a date format such as YYYY-MM-DD within BigQuery?

Or the data format has to be converted before querying in BigQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%a %b %d %Y %X GMT%z', SUBSTR("Mon May 11 2020 11:22:19 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)", 1, 33)))
```

with output

```
2020-05-11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this resource:

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE([time_zone])
```

Returns: `2016-12-25`

You can add an optional time zone as an argument to this function.
It will return date in UTC time zone if you don't pass the argument.

Resource:
[Google BigQuery standard SQL docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions)

Check this resource if you want to learn more.